# Migrating from ASP.NET-Core 3.1 to .NET6-Pitfalls when upgrading web-hosting module?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I've been migrating my intranet from ASP.Net-Core3.1 to .NET6.  So far all is well, I updated all the references.  When I first published I got an error, because I hadn't upgrade the server's core run-time.  I changed it to self-contained and the error went away.  Everything's running fine at this point, and I'm about to install the new ASP.NET Hosting Bundle (6.0) but I'm a little gun-shy.  Are there any pitfalls when upgrading the IIS Core stuff that I should watch out for before I do this.  The site's working fine as a self-contained .NET6 app running on the older 3.1 hosting bundle at the moment.

Comment: Unless there is a guide to go directly from 3.1 to 6, did you migrating step by step?

Comment: ASP.NET Hosting Bundle! That rings a bell. Installing an older version of this tool broke dotnet by messing up the path. Probably fixed now.

Comment: I did migrate step by step... but the migration guide doesn't specifically mention the hosting bundle.  I did not switch over to the new "minimal hosting model", though.  I kept startup.cs and program.cs as they were.  I did a quick look at the "breaking changes" but reading through the details of all of them is pretty onerous.  There's a list of 3.1 to 5, and then 5 to 6.  Seems like hosting part of the bundle would update the server's EntityFramework version?  Interesting to know about the path change.  I'll watch for it.

Comment: @pcalkins Don't know if it'll help, but have a look at my comprehensive [upgrade checklist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71984529/9971404), there could be something you've missed.

Comment: finally built up the courage to do this... tried to install the .NET7 hosting bundle, and got an error during the installation, so I went with the .NET6 hosting bundle installer and all went smoothly.   The odd part is now I have ".NET Core 3.1.18 - Windows Server Hosting", ".NET 7.0.5 - Windows Server Hosting", and ".NET 6.0.1 - Windows Server Hosting" showing in Programs and Features.  I thought it would uninstall the other versions.  Only runtimes showing are .NET 6.0.1 (x64) and (x86).... though I don't use them as I publish self-contained.