# Upgrade checklist for latest .NET, ASP.NET Core and EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, blazor

I'm upgrading .NET, ASP.NET Core and EF Core to the latest versions.

Is there a comprehensive migration "checklist" I can follow?

Comment: What this guide doesn't cover? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/dotnet/core/porting/

Comment: @Braiam The official guides don't cover everything - read my answer. A major upgrade needs planning and testing, not just copy-pasting from release notes. Your first link is only one of many related guides, and your second link isn't even relevant (it's not for .NET Core).

Comment: **Your question should be able to stand without the answer.** Also, there's nothing there that seems to not be covered by the guide or competent programming, like doing a dependency inventory, which the guide properly presumes that you are competent enough to do it without they telling you.

Comment: @Braiam That guide assumes nothing, it just states what's new. And there are half a dozen migration and breaking changes and new features documents. I made a checklist of all that, as well as added important upgrade steps. Most people do copy-paste these days without planning, so I think this will help many. It helped me, I used it myself when upgrading our systems. It's good to have a rigorous plan before undertaking a major upgrade - another thing the docs don't cover.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## General checklist for any version

### 1. Pre-upgrade

- If you're upgrading a non-trivial production system, ensure you have a few days to spare
- Make a list of all your third-party libraries (nugets), and visit their repos. Ensure each one supports the latest framework version - if not, then you 1) cannot upgrade yet, or 2) must find replacements for those not yet compatible with the latest framework.

### 2. Upgrade

- Checkout new git branch
- Run all tests: important to take a baseline before upgrading, to be able to compare before/after. Take note of failing tests, if any (so they can be ignored later).
- Review release notes

  - General: [v6](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-6), [v7](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-dotnet-7)
  - .NET: [v5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-5), [v6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-6), [v7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-7)
  - C#: [v9](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9), [v10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-10), [v11](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-11)
  - ASP.NET Core: [v5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/release-notes/aspnetcore-5.0), [v6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/release-notes/aspnetcore-6.0), [v7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/release-notes/aspnetcore-7.0)
  - EF Core: [v5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew), [v6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-6.0/whatsnew), [v7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew)
- Review official migration guides

  - General: [3.1 -> 5.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/31-to-50), [5.0 -> 6.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60), [6.0 -> 7.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/60-70)
  - Samples: [3.1/5.0 -> 6.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60-samples)
- Review breaking changes

  - C#: [overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/breaking-changes), [v9](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/compilers/CSharp/Compiler%20Breaking%20Changes%20-%20DotNet%205.md), [v10](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/compilers/CSharp/Compiler%20Breaking%20Changes%20-%20DotNet%206.md), [v11](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/breaking-changes/compiler%20breaking%20changes%20-%20dotnet%207)
  - ASP.NET Core: [3.1 -> 5.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/31-to-50#review-breaking-changes), [5.0 -> 6.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60#review-breaking-changes), [6.0 -> 7.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/60-70#review-breaking-changes)
  - EF Core: [v5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/breaking-changes), [v6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-6.0/breaking-changes), [v7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/breaking-changes)
- Update SDK: [v5](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/5.0), [v6](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0), [v7](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/7.0)
- Update dependencies (in `Directory.Build.props` or `MyProject.csproj`)

  - Update SDK version if necessary: [5.0 -> 6.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60#update-net-sdk-version-in-globaljson), [6.0 -> 7.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/60-70#update-net-core-sdk-version-in-globaljson)
  - Update framework: [framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/60-70#update-the-target-framework): `<TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>`
  - Update language version (if necessary): `<LangVersion>11.0</LangVersion>`
  - Update Microsoft [packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/60-70#update-package-references) named `Microsoft.AspNetCore.*` and `Microsoft.Extensions.*`
  - Update other dependencies, only if necessary (to reduce this migration's complexity). Update libraries which have been updated for the new framework version, as well as those that must be updated, e.g. non-Microsoft database providers.
  - Update relevant dotnet tools, if necessary (in `dotnet-tools.json`, or those installed globally)
- Handle breaking changes

  - Fix broken code
  - Fix broken tests; ignore failing tests which were already broken before the migration (fix them later)
- Remove obsolete workarounds. Find those workarounds that are no longer necessary due to changes/fixes in the latest framework. Typically those you've (hopefully) noted with something like `// workaround: will be fixed in v6`.
- Add new Roslyn analysers to `.editorconfig`: [v5](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/blob/main/src/NetAnalyzers/Core/AnalyzerReleases.Shipped.md#release-50), [v6](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/blob/main/src/NetAnalyzers/Core/AnalyzerReleases.Shipped.md#release-60), [v7](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/blob/main/src/NetAnalyzers/Core/AnalyzerReleases.Shipped.md#release-70)
- Rerun tests, and compare to baseline
- Update documentation

  - Update relevant project documentation
  - Search for and update version-specific links, if necessary, e.g. links to `learn.microsoft.com` often have a version number like `&view=aspnetcore-6.0` when there could be behaviour changes between versions
- Commit the git branch

### 3. Post-upgrade

- Adopt new features, if necessary and/or desired. Most new framework features are optional, so only adopt them if you really want them.
- Perform tasks necessary to satisfy your continuous integration system, if appropriate.

---

## Checklist for v6

### 3. Post-upgrade

- Adopt major new features, optional

  - Refactor for [global using directives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-10#global-using-directives)
  - Refactor for [file-scoped namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-10#file-scoped-namespace-declaration)

    - Easiest to do with `dotnet format`: [example](https://www.meziantou.net/updating-your-project-to-use-file-scoped-namespaces.htm)
    - Also add new [analysers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/formatting-rules#csharp_style_namespace_declarations) to `.editorconfig`: `csharp_style_namespace_declarations = file_scoped:suggestion` and `dotnet_diagnostic.IDE0161.severity = warning`
  - Refactor for new [minimal hosting model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60#new-hosting-model), by merging `Program.cs` and `Startup.cs`
  - Refactor for [minimal APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/release-notes/aspnetcore-6.0#minimal-apis)

---

## Checklist for v7

### 3. Post-upgrade

- Adopt major new features, optional

  - Adopt [rate limiting middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/release-notes/aspnetcore-7.0#rate-limiting-middleware-in-aspnet-core)
  - Use new "publish to container" [feature](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-builtin-container-support-for-the-dotnet-sdk)
  - Rest is mostly improvements; see what interests you in various links above

Comment: If I've forgotten something major that applies to all/most cases, then feel free to edit my answer. But if it applies only to some/niche cases, then add another answer.

Answer (score 2):

For integration test, if you are using minimal API and having a problem with accessibility on `program.cs`

add this line in the end of the `program.cs`

```cs
public partial class Program
{
    // Expose the Program class for use with WebApplicationFactory<T>
}
```

Sometime it is not enough with just this

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <InternalsVisibleTo Include ="Project.Test"/>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: How is this related to the question?

Comment: @GertArnold
When you need to upgrade your integration test to work with dotnet 6 minimal api?

Comment: I don't see how that is an indispensable part of the upgrade process. It's just another feature that .net 6 offers. We're not going to mention all new features, do we?

Comment: I don't think it is a new feature. I am talking about removing `startup.cs` here not minimal api. I think dotnet is going to use this style and deprecate startup pattern. When I upgrade my project, I would like to use the new pattern so in the long run, you don't have 2 different patterns in your company code base and confuse all new comers. In the end, it is not that hard to upgrade this style, and it does makes code cleaner. You don't have to use minimal API but I think removing `startup.cs` is a right thing to do.